# Why is the identity condition needed in the definition of a direct system?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, definition

In the exercises of Atiyah-Macdonald, it defines a direct system of $R$-modules over a directed set $I$ as a collection of $R$-modules $M_i$ and homomorphisms $\phi_{ij} : M_i \to M_j$ for each  $i\leq j$, such that $\phi_{ii}$ is the identity map of $M_i$, and $\phi_{jk} \circ \phi_{ij} = \phi_{ik}$ for $i\leq j \leq k$.

And then it constructs the direct limit $M$ of the system and proves some of its properties. My question is, I can't see why the condition $\phi_{ii}=1_{M_i}$ is needed in any of this. It does seem like a natural condition, but would anything go wrong without that condition?

Comment: Nothing would go wrong. One does not usually care for the extra generality, though. Removing that condition implies that the phi_ii are idempotent, so they determine a decomposition of each of the M_i as a direct sum of the kernel and the image of the phi_ii, and you can check that all the action happens in one of the summands.

Comment: In particular, it is not *necessary* to impose that condition, at least to carry out the construction. (One can remove all the conditions, in fact! That amounts to taking the direct limit over the diagram that comes out of the free category generated by the arrows you do have... If you don't know what this means just ignore it)

Answer (score 1):

This is necessary because a directed set is just a preorder, not a partial order; i.e., it’s not required to be antisymmetric, as a partial order is.

If a directed set were defined as a partial order in which any two elements have an upper bound, you could just leave out the homomorphisms $\phi_{ii}$. Later in the construction, where they form the quotient over a submodule generated by all elements of the form $x_i-\phi_{ij}(x_i)$ where $i\le j$ and $x_i\in M_i$, you’d then have to write $i\lt j$ instead. If you allow $i=j$ with $\phi_{ii}$ not the identity on $M_i$, you quotient out some of the structure of $M_i$, rather than just quotienting out the difference between corresponding elements in different $M_i$ as intended. The idea of a direct limit is that in a sense it contains each of the objects, and that wouldn’t be the case then.

Because a directed set is just a preorder, not a partial order, there may be $i\ne j$ with $i\le j$ and $j\le i$, so to make the whole thing work you need to include $\phi_{ji}\circ\phi_{ij}=\phi_{ii}$, and if you don’t require it to be the identity, you end up quotienting out part of the structure.

Comment: Necessary for what, exactly?